# How to calculate the coordinates of the centers of the smallest number of fixed radius circles that cover a rectangle?

Tags: c, math, geometry, logic

In Cartesian coordinates I have a rectangle with a know height h, width w and 4 corners (x,y). If i have some value r that is the fixed radius of circles, how do I calculate the center points of the smallest number of circles that will totally cover the rectangle?

Comment: "know height h, width w and 4 corners (x,y)" is over specified.  4 corners is enough, 2 corners and H/W is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refer to existing approaches and choose one, you think is more suitable for you.

I recommend to start from this [list of solutions for similar task - Circles Covering Squares](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/circovsqu/)

And, as you understand, because this optimization problem is more a mathematical than programmer, my second recommendation is to read related posts at [mathematics forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216211/what-is-the-optimal-solution-for-covering-a-rectangle-with-circles)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have examined both of them, but sadly am no closer to figuring out how to do this :(